# Laravel 5.4 - Scout error

Tags: php, laravel

I have this error which block me for anything :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider' not found
```

I was trying to remove scout and i think i removed a wrong line.
I never touched this file before.

I tried to delete vendor folder, remove the "scout" line in comper.json and did a composer update

But it's not working.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to remove `Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider` from `config/app.php` if you wish to remove the package.

Comment: @TuxxyDOS Can you accept my answer if this solves your issue please?

Comment: Sorry i forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `composer dump-autoload` It works perfectly.